# opencv 3.4 NDK on rk3399 board with Android (ver >= 7.1, API >= 26)

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

My developing environment is

- firefly rk3399 board with Android 7.1.2 (ver >= 7.1, API > 26)
- opencv 3.4.2 NDK (ver >= 3.4)

What i have to is

- retrieving camera frame on cv::Mat.

I built a App with opencv NDK and as a result i got an error like below

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/opencv/libc++.so" needed or dlopened by "/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"
```

So i move library file on /system to /opencv (created by me).

```
static {
        System.load("/opencv/libc++.so");
        System.load("/opencv/libopencv_java3.so");
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
```

but it brought me same error.

I read this [article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.html) and it said officially starting with API 24 applications are no longer able to load non-NDK platform libraries.

could you help me to use opencv 3.4 NDK on API > 26?

Comment: When built correctly, neither your `libnative-lib.so` nor `libopencv_java3.so` should look for `libc++.so`. If you use shared STL, this could be `libc++_shared.so`, supplied with NDK, and you should pack it in your APK next to `libnative-lib.so`.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Thank you.
Does 'pack in to APK'  means move libopencv files on data folder?
some search result said that /data diretory is where external library placed.
so i place it under /data, it worked (but has 'opencv package manager not found problem' yet..).

Comment: maybe I am missing something. Do you use *OpenCV Manager*? Does your app come as an APK, or you build it as part of AOSP?

Comment: part of AOSP. Im also consider to put library files in vendor folder by flashing customized rk3399's Android source at next milestone. but if possible, I just want to import lib file in studio like jar, not moving lib file manually through adb. I think maybe there is some other way to solve 'Application can't not load 3rd party external NDK libraries which are located in system/lib64' issue. I am really want to know what is private and public library and how can i convert private lib to public for using it.

Thanks you.

Comment: If your app is `system`, you cannot avoid installing the native libraries under `/system/` or `/vendor/`. The AOSP build usually takes care of packaging these libraries correctly in the system image, you don't need a separate `adb push`.

Comment: If so, think there is no choice :) . Anyway, thank you for helping me Alex. Have a good day :)